# Anyone have experience of using Groovy/Grails with Eclipse Virgo Snaps?

Tags: grails, groovy, osgi, eclipse-virgo

I want to create a pluggable set of applications, and I've come across Virgo Snaps (formerly SpringSource Slices) which looks like it's exactly what I need, but I can't find any Groovy/Grails resources on how to tap into it.

I would ideally like to create OSGi modules that I can deploy to the Virgo server, which can have awareness of each other.

Does anybody have any experience, or (pref) links about this, or is this something I'll have to look into from scratch? Is this even the correct direction to achieve what I want to do?

Comment: Snaps projects are essentially composed of nested WARs.  Groovy can provide servlets, and be packaged as OSGi bundles with services.  I think you just need to leverage Groovy's existing servlet and OSGi support.

Comment: I think this was part of my confusion, I was under the impression that Snaps also had to be OSGi modules too? I'm having no end of difficulty getting my application to compile using the OSGi plugin, it seems there are oodles of dependencies that look pretty broken. I suppose it's back to the (OSGi) drawing board... Cheers ear cam

Comment: Sorry I should have been more precise, snaps are nested WABs (Web Application Bundles - essentially skinny WAR with OSGi MANIFEST.MF).  What plugin are you referring to, maven-bundle-plugin?  If so, this might be of use http://www.grails.org/plugin/osgi

Comment: No, it was the Grails OSGi plugin that you've linked to that I'm having trouble with - I should probably open another question, as it's quite a different problem. It seems everybody points to that plugin, I must be doing something a bit dumb!

Comment: May be try converting a simple Java Snaps example, module at a time to Groovy?  (AFAIK the maven-bundle-plugin should work fine with Groovy, though you may need to tweak the Import-Package config)